# PHP strtotime function quandry

Tags: php, date

I am new to the world of coding as well as PHP and befuddled by what the `'-01'` does in the code below.

```
strtotime($someYear . '-' . $someMonth . '-01');
```

Comment: See also: [Date and time formats as understood by `strtotime`, `date_create` and the DateTime object constructor](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

Comment: A cleaner approach would be `mktime(0,0,0,$someMonth,1,$someYear);`

Comment: @Frank Farmer - Thanks. Why is that deemed cleaner?

Comment: it's considered cleaner by some because it's a function that takes specific arguments in a specific order, as opposed to relying on the format parsing rules of `strtotime`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's selecting the first day of the month.

`.` is the string concatenation operator in PHP, and PHP will convert numbers to strings automatically.

So let's say you had:

```
$someYear = 2011; 
$someMonth = 5;
```

And you want the timestamp of the start of that month, you could it do it with that:

```
$someDate = $someYear . '-' . $someMonth . '-01';  // equivalent to "2011-5-01"
strtotime($someDate);
```

This is a bit ugly, but it works.

Comment: @therefromhere - Thanks. But even if I don't specify it, I still get the same result. So why specify it?

Comment: @therefromhere - Thanks. That's very clear however why not write it as 

`$someDate = $someYear . '-' . $someMonth . '-' .'01';`

The `-01` confused me as a deduction of some sort e.g. less 1 month or day, etc.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey, yes, it's a quick and dirty approach.  It's best to be explicit about your format, since `strtotime` will guess (which is what it's doing when you don't specify the day number), but it can get confused.

Comment: @therefromhere - why is that a 'dirty approach'?

Comment: @Peanuts, it's considered dirty by some that don't know the `strtotime` format rules, or don't trust them.  I personally fall into the latter camp for some things (supported formats have changed over time, meaning some formats doesn't work under older PHP versions), though passing it a `YYYY-MM-DD` is about as unambiguous as you can possibly get.

Answer (score 3):

Sets the day to the first in month, i.e if $someYear is '1999' and $someMonth is '01' this would yield

```
strtotime("1999-01-01");
```

Comment: Thanks. Akin to what I asked `therefromhere`, why specify it when I get the same result when excluding it?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - you can write the date in many forms, i.e strtotime("first day of january 1999") is also valid. Have a look at the manual for some more examples http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php